# Multiple inputs from one input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function to append an input to a list. I want it so that when you input `280 2` the list becomes `['280', '280']` instead of `['280 2']`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> number, factor = input().split()
280 2
>>> [number]*int(factor)
['280', '280']
```

Remember that concatenating a list with itself with the * operator can have [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) if your list contains mutable elements - but in your case it's fine.

edit:

Solution that can handle inputs without a factor:

```
>>> def multiply_input():
...     *head, tail = input().split()
...     return head*int(tail) if head else [tail]
... 
>>> multiply_input()
280 3
['280', '280', '280']
>>> multiply_input()
280
['280']
```

Add error checking as needed (for example for empty inputs) depending on your use case.

Comment: I like it, but it appears it runs into an error when you only enter 280, I could use ugly code like I usually do to fix this but do you know of any sleek solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import repeat

mes=input("please write your number and repetitions:").split()
listt= []
listt.extend(repeat(int(mes[0]), int(mes[1]))   

#repeat(object [,times]) -> create an iterator which returns the object
#for the specified number of times.  If not specified, returns the object
#endlessly.
```

Comment: Please consider explaining the rationale behind your code to make it easier for those who are trying to learn from it.

Comment: Thank you! I was going insane trying to .append my inputs when I (unbeknownst to me) actually wanted to .extend them.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the case with unspecified number of repetitions by extending the parsed input with a list containing 1. You can then slice the list to leave the first 2 items (in case the number of repetitions was provided, that `[1]` will be discarded)

```
number, rep = (input().split() + [1])[:2]
[number] * int(rep)
```

Comment: A bit of text would help the reader understand quicker your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code provides exception handling against no second number being provided with in put.

```
def addtolist():
    number = input("Enter number: ")
    try:
        factor = input("Enter factor: ")
    except SyntaxError:
        factor = 1
    for i in range(factor):
        listname.append(number)
```